# Opengl Textures dont display but give corrupted double linked list error

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I've been playing with textures for some time and i just can't get it to work

Here is the code

```
#include "App.h"

std::array <float, 4> background_col = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0}  ;
std::string name                     = "OpenGL"                 ;
std::string icon                     = "data/images/dot.png"    ;
const int width                      = 800                      ;
const int height                     = 800                      ;
bool anti_aliasing                   = true                     ;
bool FPS_60_CAP                      = true                     ;

MVP mvp;

void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{

}

void App::run()
{
    Window window(true, anti_aliasing);
    window.make_Window(glfwCreateWindow(width, height, name.c_str(), NULL, NULL), key_callback, icon);
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    mvp.view = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)width, 0.0f, (float)height);

    Renderer renderer;
    Player player;

    // redesighn with errors in mind

    // 1. TODO: Implement Text
    // 2. TODO: Implement UI


    std::vector<float> vertexes = {
        200, 200, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        200, 600, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        600, 600, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        600, 200, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
    };
    
    std::vector<uint32_t> indexes = {0, 1, 2, 3};

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.window))
    {
        glClearColor(background_col[0], background_col[1], background_col[2], background_col[3]);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        warn(0);
        Shader shader("shaders/text.shader");
        shader.useShader();
        warn(1);
        Texture tex("data/images/dot.png");
        tex.Bind();
        warn(2);
        shader.uniformMat4Float("u_projection_matrix", mvp.projection * mvp.view * mvp.model);
        shader.uniformInt({0}, "tex");
        warn(3);
        VBO vbo;
        VAO vao;
        IBO ibo;
        warn(4);
        vbo.write(vertexes.data(), vertexes.size() * sizeof(float));
        ibo.write(indexes.data(), indexes.size() * sizeof(uint32_t));
        warn(5);
        ibo.bind();
        vbo.bind();
        vao.bind();
        warn(6);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (const void *)(sizeof(float) * 0));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (const void *)(sizeof(float) * 2));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 8, (const void *)(sizeof(float) * 6));
        warn(7);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, indexes.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
        warn(8);
        ibo.unbind();
        vbo.unbind();
        vao.unbind();
        warn(9);
        tex.unBind();
        tex.~Texture();
        warn(10);
        vbo.~VBO();
        vao.~VAO();
        ibo.~IBO();
        warn(11);
        shader.deleteShader();
        warn(12);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window.window);
        glfwSwapInterval(FPS_60_CAP);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    
    alcCloseDevice(player.Device);
    window.~Window();
}
```

the texture class:

```
#include "Core.h"

Texture::Texture(std::string path)
{
    this->path = path;
    this->bpp = 0;
    this->height = 0;
    this->width = 0;
    this->localbuffer = nullptr;
    this->TexID = 0;

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    localbuffer = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, 4);

    glGenTextures(1, &TexID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TexID);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, localbuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 

    if (localbuffer) { stbi_image_free(localbuffer); }
    else { info("h"); }
}
        
void Texture::Bind(uint32_t slot)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
}

void Texture::unBind()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 
}

Texture::~Texture()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &TexID);
}
```

and the shader:

```
#shader vertex

#version 400 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 Pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 vColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec4 color;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 u_projection_matrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projection_matrix * Pos;
    color = vColor;
    TexCoord = vTexCoord;
}


#shader fragment

#version 400 core

in vec4 color;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    vec4 texcol = texture(tex, TexCoord);
    gl_FragColor = texcol;
}
```

it just stays blank and displays this error

```
corrupted double-linked list
```

it is important to mention this error happens on the second frame

The code that I know works because I've got textures to display before correctly is:

the Shader class

VAO VBO and IBO

EDIT: after the fix from rafix07 it doesn't crash anymore it just doesn't display

EDIT2:

I've implemented glDebugMessageCallback, and it gives me this error:

source: 33352

type: 33361

id: 1

severity: 33387

length: 130

GL ERROR!: Shader Stats: SGPRS: 24 VGPRS: 24 Code Size: 72 LDS: 0 Scratch: 0 Max Waves: 10 Spilled SGPRs: 0 Spilled VGPRs: 0 PrivMem VGPRs: 0

Answer (score -1):

Remove all explicit invocations of destructors, like:

```
tex.~Texture();
```

You get *corrupted double-linked list* because you deallocate a resource twice: first time by calling destructor explicitly and the second one when destructor is called at the end of scope within object is defined.

```
{
  Texture tex;
  // ...
  tex.~Texture();  // texture is deallocated and id texture is dangling reference
  // <-- dtor of tex is called implicitly, and the same id texture is deleted again leading to crash
}
```

Comment: But it still doesn't display after the fix